# Django App : Perform arithmetic operation on two fields in database and store result in third field in DB while adding data in form

Tags: python, django

I have One form in my application with different fields from which i need to subtracts value of one field from other and store result in third field on the fly in Database.

Example i have 2 fields  :
1. Cost of PR Basic & 2. Cost of PO Basic

Need to calculate Delta : Cost of PO Basic - Cost of PR Basic.
Delta is also field in database table.
In models.py i have

`class PR_Data(models.Model) 
    Cost_PR_Basic_INR = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19,decimal_places=2)
    Cost_Of_PO_Basic_INR = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19,decimal_places=2)
    Delta = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19,decimal_places=2, editable=True)`

So how can i calculate delta from values entered in other two fields and store result in Delta field.

Thanks in advance..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `views.py:`

do something like this:

```
pr_data = PR_Data()
pr_data.Cost_PR_Basic_INR = <value1>
pr_data.Cost_Of_PO_Basic_INR = <value2>
pr_data.Delta = <value1> - <value2>
pr_data.save()
```

just an idea how it should work, not the complete code ;)